# Replace a string's special characters using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion

the string looks something like below:
**/1/2/3/4** however I want to replace this with **?1=2&3=4**.
I am planning to use REReplace in ColdFusion.
Could you suggest me a regex for this ?
I also thought of using loops but stuck either way...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What if the string looked like, "4/3/5/2/5"?  Or is that possible?

Comment: well it could be either /1/2 or /1/2/3/4 strings wont be repeated.. hardcoded :) & if it's /1/2 i want this to look like ?1=2

Comment: *thought of using loops* Ignoring optimality for a moment, what exactly did you try? Seems easy enough to split the list into an array on `/`. Then loop through it and build the new string using the current and next index.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a Search Engine Sage url into a standard querystring? If so, there are rewrite rules for Apache and IIS that can handle that for you.

Comment: @Leigh Yes i am working on loop thing..

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo yes you caught it right but i am pretty much confused with .htaccess thing :( so thought to modify my cgi..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit cumbersome without making it more manageable using a loop as @Leigh suggested; but you can use the following on string inputs that contain even occurrences of `n/m` in the format you described:

```
var s = "/1/2/3/4/5/6";
s.replace(/^\//,'?').replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g,'$1=$2').replace(/\//g,'&')
// => "?1=2&3=4&5=6"
```